# How did Descartes made a logical skeptic argument against logic, without falling into a paradox, in his Metaphysical Meditations? Is it actually valid

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-mathematics, philosophy-of-logic, descartes, skepticism

René Descartes seems to have made some arguments against logic and mathematics in his Metaphysical Meditations, however it seems that these arguments are still logical, and the problem is whether that does not lead into some paradox, similar to the liar's paradox, as it seems to be logically showing that logic is invalid, and therefore that same logical demonstration would be invalid.

He later seems to defend the validity of logic and mathematics stating that they are "clear and distinct", however this actually does not seem to be a logical argument, or even something intelligible.

I would think that probably you cannot base the validity of logic on logic itself, that there is need for some "axioms" that are sustained on nothing (or on experience?), on which then logic can be based.

You could say that his skeptic arguments are about me being sabotaged by the evil genius, therefore not being able to be sure I am thinking logically or not, but even then, there is still the question as to why, if I was doubting of anything, I did not doubt about logic itself. But if the axioms are just assumed, then I do not know them, and therefore they cannot count as indubitable knowledge neither.

And yet, as I said, it seems that it is not even possible to logically doubt about logic, and question myself this. So:

How is it even possible to continue any argumentation after this "logical self destruction"? How exactly did Descartes achieved to justify such self destruction?

How did he continue after this? Was it an acceptable way to continue?

Did other philosophers propose other ways to overcome this issue? I am thinking probably Husserl, Russell, Whitehead or Hume proposed something, but I have not been able yet to identify their arguments about this.

Comment: Because when one is arguing *against* a point they are free to use the point to disprove it, that is how proofs by contradiction work. If one can logically prove that logic is invalid then logic *is* invalid. For analogy with the Liar paradox one would have to *also* prove that making the contrary assumption, that logic is invalid, leads to a contradiction. But it is hard to see how they would prove anything without logic.

Comment: There's a reason why Descartes is widely regarded as one of the founders of modern western philosophy, as his Cognito provocation caused similar skepticisms in general and most later philosophers tried to deal with the fallout from this. The proposition itself is a convincing metaphysical claim, not a proof of logical inconsistency using logic. And the antecedent is not just about thinking which is mundane and machine can easily think (artificially) these days, it's more about the ability of self-doubt as *awakening* of a kind of *self-awareness*, not merely aware of some outward knowledge...

Comment: "René Descartes seems to have made some arguments against logic and mathematics in his Metaphysical Meditations..." Where???